# Create a mathematical sequence

Tags: python, sequence, fibonacci

i need to create a mathematical sequence of type:
P(n)= P(n-1) + P(n-2)
We know that P(0)=0 and P(1)=1
I really struggle creating a sequence, i tried to create it, here is some of what I’ve written...

```
def fibonacci(n):
    number = 0
    if n == 0:
        number = 0
        return (number)
    if n == 1:
        number = 1
        return (number)
    if n > 1:
        def compute(limit):
            for x in range(2, limit):
                fibonacci(x) = fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci(x-2)
        for i in range(0, n):
            number += compute(i)
```

Comment: Please edit into your question what’s wrong with your code -for example you might show the output you are getting from your code and what you expect/want. If there’s an error message put the full text into your question.

Comment: You are overthinking this way too much. Try to write out, in plain English words, each step of the process, and then relate it to the code that you have. You will find that the code tries to do extra, unnecessary things.

Comment: I know, I’m trying to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** you don't need to use brackets when you use 'return' statement
**Solution:**

```
def fibonacci(n):
    number = 0
    if n == 0:
        number = 0
        return number
    if n == 1:
        number = 1
        return number
    if n > 1:
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
```

This code works fine, but u can calculate fibonacci more effective if u will use dynamic programming
**Example:**

```
fibonacci = [0,1]
for i in range(2,n+1):
 fibonacci.append(fibonacci[i-1]+fibonacci[i-2])
print(fibonacci[-1])
```